# Can't retrieve user's TextBox input

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a program with two Forms:

Form 1 has a `TextBox` and a `Button`.
Form2 has a `DataGridView`.

Then I have a class with a constructor that accepts a string as parameter:

```
public SymbolData(string symbol)
{ /* Do stuff */ }
```

The `DataGridView` displays the data from a table defined in `SymbolData` when user clicks the button.

My problem is that when I click the button the string retrieved from the textbox is the one I inserted in its Text property regardless of what is inserted in the `TextBox` enter code herewhen the program is running

Here is where I create `SymbolData` instance:

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SymbolData sd = new SymbolData(f1.textButton1.Text);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = sd.Table;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to pass the user's input from the `TextBox` in my `SymbolData` object's constructor when I call it?

Comment: Glad to see your problem is solved. Please let me note two things about posting to SO though: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing and and will often get  wrong answers from other types of targets, like WPF or ASP... Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! - Also: I have deleted C# from the title as it is already in the tag and only essential tags should be repeated in the Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to instantiate `SymbolData` in `Form2` then have your form2 constructor accept a string parameter and pass that argument to `SymbolData` constructor like below

```
public Form2(string form1data)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SymbolData sd = new SymbolData(form1data);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = sd.Table;
}
```

Then in your `Form1` button click event get a instance of `Form2` and pass textbox data

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this.textButton1.Text.Trim());
  frm2.Showdialog();
}
```

Comment: Don't really like this method, surely it works but is not very OOP.

You should probably think of a singleton class that is used to exchange data between the two classes

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways but most of the ways will require an event to be created.  You can create a button on the form, when you double click it a click event is created.  You then can pass your text in that way.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SymbolData sd = new SymbolData(f1.textButton1.Text);
    }
```

You can also create an event on the textbox, such as Keypress, keyup, keydown, you can find those events on the properties of the text box and click the lightning bolt on the top of the panel to see the events.